# how do i fix error caused by Observable.throw(err.json())?

Tags: angular, observable

```
Uncaught TypeError: err.json is not a function
```

this is the error I get when I try to execute this code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

const config = require("../../../config")

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
  public host = config.host

  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ) { }

  getKey(key) {
    return this.http.get(`http://${this.host}/api/keys/${key}`)
      .map((response: Response) => {
        return response.json()
      })
      .catch((err: Response) => Observable.throw(err.json()));
  }
}
```

The last line is producing the error. Am I missing a dependency or something?
I'm pretty sure I've always done  errors in angular like this so I'm not sure why is producing the error right now. Did they update it so I have to handle errors differently now?

Comment: It's just my guess, but probably you're getting that TypeError because http errors are unpredictable and you can't give for granted that it's parsable as json.
Try casting **err** as *any* and invoke *.json()* only if **err** is instance of *Response*

Comment: nevermind, I'm trolling. The files just weren't updated :)

Comment: @EricChu meaning to say your code above is actually working?

Comment: @KelvinLowEeHahn correct